# `Not assignable to param of type never` error while using `in`

Tags: typescript

I simplified my problem with most simple example as shown here.

```js
type Text = 'text1' | 'text2';
const fun: { [key in Text]: (item: key) => string } = {
  text1: (t: 'text1'): string => t,
  text2: (t: 'text2'): string => t,
};

function toString1<T extends Text>(node: T): string {
  return fun[node](node); // <-- error here on second node
 }
```

The error is `Argument of type T is not assignable to parameter of type never`

It works fine if I replace `T` with `text1` or `text2` but fails with generic. Any leads to understand this behaviour .

---

*Update*:
Full example code :

```js
type Role1 = {type: 'role1', .... } 
type Role2 = {type: 'role2', ... }

type Roles = {
  'role1': Role1; 
  'role2' : Role2;
} 

function hasPermission<T extends keyof Roles>( role : Roles[T]){
 const roleCheck : {[key in keyof Roles]: (role: Roles[key])=> boolean} = {
   role1 : ( role: Role1) => false, 
   role2 : ( role: Role2) => true,
 } ;  
 
  return roleCheck[role.type](role);

}


// excluding actual implementation ofcourse
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBASg9gGwgRigXigb1JAXFAcgCdEUCoBfKAWACgdp4kAmdLB-Y058iuuhrFIBnNpjpRCJJMgL4mKANw1akri3LzuiulX60AxnAB2w4FGkQAwgAsIBgNZR8mANoOIIKAEtjUDyBwAGZCSMIAuvgAFJZaYe6e4QCUaAB8UABGcKQAhsZUGOKqlqjRFqRxKEno6UE5CMIQADQq5SzOUFFtEJXM1WlQwEQArs26UMr6QcPGBsDeJlA2OcIAChBEALbewsILxgA8ACpQEAAewBDGACaiAcGhEMKpXZYdCsKuR8lFkkQQwGGRD8lls9gcrksADoGOEYqQkjpaBQgA)

Comment: I think you mean type Text1 = 'text1' | 'text2';  (missing the "1" in the type name).

Comment: I'm having trouble figuring out what the code is intended to do. Can you explain a little more?

Comment: I figured out it might happen :D . But tried to keep it simple. I will edit with complete example.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure I know what you are aiming for, but if I do understand correctly, maybe restructure to something like this, below? I added a few "permissions" to each role in case that is what hasPermission() should be checking.

```
enum Role {
    role1 = 'role1',
    role2 = 'role2'
}

const roleSettings = {
    [Role.role1]: {
        accessLevel: 'blue',
        isAdmin: false
    },
    [Role.role2]: {
        accessLevel: 'green',
        isAdmin: true
    }
} as const;


const hasPermission = (role: Role, requiredPermissionsForAction: {
    accessLevel?: string,
    isAdmin?: boolean
}) => {
    const roleData = roleSettings[role];
    if (requiredPermissionsForAction.accessLevel !== undefined && requiredPermissionsForAction.accessLevel !== roleData.accessLevel) return false;
    if (requiredPermissionsForAction.isAdmin && !roleData.isAdmin) return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: This certainly gives me more ideas. I will try this . What I am trying to achieve is to build a plugin system where I provide interface `{ [role type] : role check implementation}` . I will check if I can do the same using enums and get back to you . Thankyou for your effort . But I still dont understand the above error :D

Comment: Actually its not just roles, I need to do a lot of logic inside those functions :) , sometimes call API

Comment: You can actually put a function in the dictionary, so instead of "accessLevel" you could have "authChecker: (u: userInfo) => return role1auth(u) for example

Comment: Yeah , this works.  I need to rewrite lot of code, but this seems to be the right way to handle these . I am not marking this is as answer , as it doesnt answer the error in specific. But thanks a lot !!